# Use Linq Expression object inside and outside query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to accept a `Func` as a parameter to a function, and then use it both inside and outside a Linq query.

Here, `idSelector` is a `Func` of some kind which will return a particular SubLedger id in the `Transaction` object (e.g. `t => t.SubLedger1`).

```
public class Transaction {
    public int SubLedger1 { get; set; }
    public int SubLedger2 { get; set; }
    public int SubLedger3 { get; set; }

    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<Transaction> GetSubLedger(DateTime StartDate, Func<Transaction, int> idSelector) {

    // simply returns IQueryable of all
    DbSet<Transaction> txns = txnRepo.GetAll(); 

    // get opening balance for each sub ledger
    var subLedgers = txns.Where(t => t.Date < StartDate)
        .GroupBy(idSelector, t => t, (id, txn) => new { ID = id, Balance = txn.Sum(t => t.Amount) })
        .ToDictionary(t => t.ID, t => t.Balance);

    // fill running balance
    var filtered = txns.Where(t => t.Date >= StartDate).ToList();
    foreach (var t in filtered)
    {
        t.Balance = subLedgers[idSelector.Invoke(t)].Balance += t.Amount;
    }

    return filtered;
}
```

I need to use `idSelector` in two places: first in the Linq query to group all transactions into `subLedgers`, and second to get the running balance for the particular subledger in the filtered results. I realize that Linq requires an `Expression<...>` instead, but I can't quite figure out how to Invoke that in the second context.

It's possible I'm going about this the wrong way, is there some other way I should try? This question may also be a little muddled, I did try to pare down the code sample as much as possible, so please ask me if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Compile` to get the invokeable method from the expression:

```
t.Balance = subLedgers[idSelector.Compile()(t)].Balance += t.Amount;
```

(Assuming idSelector is an `Expression<Func<Transaction, int>>`.)

Comment: I'd store that compiled method in a local variable so you only have to compile it once.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. It was the syntax for that second statement that was really stumping me (googling for Linq Expression is tricky!).

Comment: @TimS. I also followed your suggestion. Thanks!